# How to change stack push() the second result's next is [object]?

Tags: javascript, stack

I was building a Stack data structure

and i meet a problem

the result is not what i wanted

Original result is

> Stack { top: Node {
>        value: 'Youtube',
>        next: Node { value: 'Google', next: [Node] } },
>     bottom: Node { value: 'Twitter', next: null },
>     length: 3 }

What i want in result is

> Stack { top: Node {
>        value: 'Youtube',
>        next: Node { value: 'Google', next: [Object] } },
>     bottom: Node { value: 'Twitter', next: null },
>     length: 3 }

I think the problem is in my push() method.

How to turn next[Node] into next[Object]?

Here is my JS:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value){
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Stack {
  constructor(){
  this.top = null;
  this.bottom = null;
  this.length = 0;
  }
  peek() {
    if(this.top){
      return this.top;
    }else{
      return 'Empty';
    }
  }
  push(value){
     let node = new Node(value);
     if(this.top){
      node.next=this.top;
      this.top=node;
     }else{
       this.top=node;
        this.bottom=node;
      }
        this.length++;
        return this;
      }
     pop(){
        if(this.top===this.bottom){
        this.bottom=null;
       }
     if(this.top){
         let itemTop=this.top;
         this.top=this.top.next;
         this.length--;
          return this;
      }else{
         console.log('Stack is empty')
         return false;
       }
      }
     isEmpty(){
         return this.length>=1
     }
    }

    const myStack = new Stack();
    myStack.push("Twitter");
    myStack.push('Google');
    myStack.push('Youtube');
    //should return Stack { top: Node { value: 'Youtube', next: Node { value: 'Google', next: [Object] } }, bottom: Node { value: 'Twitter', next: null }, length: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already correct. `[Object]` is a string representation of an object in javascript to avoid nested hell which can confuse user. That's just the way javascript is.

You can use JSON.stringify() to see the exact representation of your object in string.

Or you can try console.log in the browser.

Here is the result when i console.log your object in browser.

[image]

Comment: So you mean i don't have to changed the code?Because my push method is fine?

Comment: Yep. The value is already correct. It's just a matter of visual representation.

Comment: OK,Thanks for your answer!